# Spectrum and Galois groups.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field, and $A=\mathrm{Spec}(k[T_1,\ldots,T_d])$, and $\bar{k}$ an algebraic closure. How is $A$ related to $\mathrm{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ ? I assume that one might express as as quotient by a group action of Gal. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way they might be related. A choice of an algebraically closed overfield $\overline{k}/k$ corresponds to taking a geometric point $\xi$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$, and the fundamental group of $\operatorname{Spec}(k)$ with respect to this geometric point is precisely the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(k^{\operatorname{sep}}/k)$, where $k$ is the separable closure of $k$ in $\overline{k}$. (This is the starting point of Grothendieck's Galois theory.)

Now, given any connected scheme $A$, a field $k$, and a $k$-point $x$ of $A$, the fundamental group functor induces (up to conjugacy, depending on your choice of $x$) a group homomorphism $$\pi_1(\operatorname{Spec}(k)) \to \pi_1(A).$$

Comment: While this sounds interesting, I was thinking of something more elementary, such as http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf page 105, Example 6.